How to keep the connection between a domain name and an ec2 instance after IP change?
I am running an EC2 instance with dynamic IP, the IP address changes each time the instance is stopped/restarted. I noticed the Public ipv4 domain of the instance is simply ec2-[ip].compute-1.amazonaws.com, which changes according to the new IP. I wonder if an EC2 instance has a permanent DNS name that are not tied to its IP, such as [instance id].amazonaws.com, which I can set a permanent CNAME on my name server?

Consider allocating an Elastic IP ("EIP") and associating it with the instance.  Elastic IPs won't change until you disassociate and deallocate them, and I don't believe they cost more than a normal public IP address as long as you have them associated with something.

sorry I was wrong, I was using normal IP assignment, instead of elastic IP. The IP changes each time I stop and restart the instance, which is intended -- I do want to change to a new IP from time to time, but I want the same instance be tied to a static domain name.

If you want the IP to change, but you want the domain name to always point to the instance, then the only option is to update the DNS record with the new IP address every time you start the instance. You could automate this with a startup script on the instance. The actual solution to this is to not let the IP change by using an Elastic IP as mentioned above, or to place a load balancer in front of the instance and point the domain name to the load balancer. But it seems like you have some undisclosed reason for wanting the IP to change.

EC2 doesn't have a permanent DNS hostname independent of their IP address by default. but there's some work around.
1 - you can get yourself an Elastic IP address and associate it with your EC2 instance, then the DNS name will remain tied to this static address.
2 - you can also place an ALB in front of the EC2, and then the ALB will always have a fixed DNS name, that doesn't change, regardless of the underlying IP addresses or status, and can provide you with much scalability and elasticity.
